# if $BA^k = 0$ and $A=A^t$ then $BA = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been trying to prove the following:

> If $BA^k = 0$ and $A=A^t$ then $BA = 0$

with no success so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for my own question:

$\displaystyle A=A^{t}$ thus $A$ is diagonalizable. It follows that there exists a diagonal matrix $\displaystyle D$ such that $\displaystyle A=P^{-1} DP$.

Thus, we get: $\displaystyle B\left( P^{-1} DP\right)^{k}=0\Rightarrow BP^{-1} D^{k} P=0$. Let's multiply by $\displaystyle P^{-1}$ : $\displaystyle \Rightarrow BP^{-1} D^{k} PP^{-1} =0\Rightarrow BP^{-1} D^{k} =0$. Let's denote $C=\displaystyle BP^{-1}$.

We get:

$\displaystyle C\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha ^{k}_{1} &  & \\
 & \ddots& \\
 &  & \alpha ^{k}_{n}
\end{pmatrix} \ =0$. Thus, for every colum $\displaystyle c_{i} \in C$ we know that $\displaystyle c_{i} \alpha ^{k}_{i} \ =\ 0$. Thus, for every colum $\displaystyle c_{i} \in C$ also $\displaystyle c_{i} \alpha _{i} \ =\ 0$.

It follows that:

$\displaystyle C\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha _{1} &  & \\
 & \ddots& \\
 &  & \alpha _{n}
\end{pmatrix} \ =0$. Meaning $\displaystyle BP^{-1} D\ =\ 0$. Let's multiply by $\displaystyle P$, we get:

$\displaystyle BP^{-1} DP\ =\ 0\ \Rightarrow BA\ =\ 0$

Answer (score 2):

Presumably $A$ is a **real** symmetric matrix, and therefore can be diagonalized, so we may assume $A$ is diagonal.  Then $A^k$ is also diagonal.  $B A^k$ is obtained by multiplying  column $j$ of $B$ by the $a_{jj}^k$.  So $B A^k = 0$ iff the columns of $B$ corresponding to nonzero diagonal elements of $A^k$ are $0$, and of course $a_{jj}^k = 0$ iff $a_{jj} = 0$.

EDIT: The statement is not true for a complex symmetric (non-hermitian) matrix.
For example, consider $$ A = \pmatrix{-i & 1\cr 1 & i},\ A^2 = \pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr} $$

Comment: How do you assume that $A^K$ is diagonal?

Comment: If $D = S A S^{-1}$ is diagonal, $B A = 0$ iff $S B A S^{-1} = (S B S^{-1}) D = 0$
and $BA^k = 0$ iff $SB A^k S^{-1} = (S B S^{-1}) D^k=0$.  So if the statement is true for $D$, it is true for $A$.

Comment: I saw your edit, the answer assumed that $A,B$ are real

Answer (score 1):

Presumably we are given that $k$ is a positive integer.

**Outline of Proof:** It suffices to prove that if $A = A^T$, then $\operatorname{im}(A^k) = \operatorname{im}(A)$ for all positive $k$. To prove this, you could use the fact that $\ker(A) = \operatorname{im}(A)^\perp$, from which it follows that that $\ker (A) \cap \operatorname{im}(A) = \{0\}$, from which it follows that the restriction of $A$ to its image is invertible, from which it follows that $\operatorname{im}(A^k) = \operatorname{im}(A)$ for all positive $k$.

Answer (score 1):

By taking the adjoint, it is enough to prove $A^nB=0\implies AB=0$.

Suppose $A^2B=0$. Then for any vector $x$, $$\|ABx\|^2=\langle x,B^*A^*ABx\rangle=\langle x,B^*A^2Bx\rangle=0$$ so $AB=0$.

By induction, $A^{2^n}B=0\implies AB=0$. But then $A^kB=0$ implies $A^{2^m}B=0$ for $m$ large enough, hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

using the **Frobenius Rank Inequality**, over reals
supposing  $ \text{rank}\big(A\big) =r$

$0\leq \text{rank}\big(BA\big)  + r= \text{rank}\big(BA\big) + \text{rank}\big(AA^{k-1}\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(BA^k\big) + \text{rank}\big(A\big) = 0 +r$
$\longrightarrow \text{rank}\big(BA\big) = 0$

the key insight is
$r = \text{rank}\big(A\big) = \text{rank}\big(A^{2}\big)=...= \text{rank}\big(A^{k}\big)$
this is implied by diagonalizablity or more simply that
$\operatorname{ker} \big(A\big)\cap \operatorname{image}\big(A\big) =\big\{\mathbf 0\big\}$